# Solve a system of ODEs in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by transforming to polar coordinates in the $x,y$-plane and deduce the place $z=0$ is attracting

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm considering the system $\dot{x}=zy, \dot{y}=-zx, \dot{z}=-z^3$.

I wish to show that (i) the plane $z=0$ is an attracting invariant set, (ii) $z^2$ is a Lyapunov function for this system, and (iii) that the $\omega$-limit set for the orbit of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ with $x_0^2+y_0^2>0$ and $z_0\neq 0$ is a circle on the plane $z=0$.

I have been given a hint to first solve the equations by transforming into polar coordinates in the $x,y$-plane.

Upon doing so, my system became $\dot{r}=0, \dot{\theta}=-z, \dot{z}=-z^3$. However, trying to solve this appears to give not so nice solutions.

(i) It is clear that the plane $z=0$ is invariant as each point on this plane is a fixed point. I am struggling to show that this is attracting though: intuitively, I guess it is because when $z<0$ we have $\dot{z}>0$ so you would move upwards towards the $z=0$ plane, and similarly for $z>0$.

(ii) This is clear, since it is continuous and $\frac{d(z^2)}{dt} = 2z\dot{z} = -2z^4 \leq 0$ so $z^2$ is non-increasing along orbits.

(iii) I honestly have no idea how to do this part; any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that the derivative of the Lyapunov function is negative shows that $z=0$ is attracting (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function#Definition_of_a_Lyapunov_function)).
From the system $\dot{r}=0$, $\dot{\theta}=-z$, $\dot{z}=-z^3$, it is clear that for $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ given with $z_0\neq 0$, we have $x_0^2+y_0^2=r_0^2$ is constant. In particular,
$$
\frac{d\theta}{dz}=\frac{\frac{d\theta}{dt}}{\frac{dz}{dt}}=\frac{1}{z^2}.
$$
As $|z|\to 0$, this shows on the $(z,\theta)$ plane that when $z\to 0^+$, $\theta \to -\infty$ and when $z\to 0^-$, $\theta \to \infty$. Hence, the trajectory never stops traveling in a circle with radius $r_0$, with the $z$ coordinate converging to the $z=0$ plane.